# EAS android build crash on camera launch

Tags: android, expo

App crashes only with (internal) android build (not with expo, not with standalone internal ios build)
Permission request before launching the comp with the camera
=> `const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync()`; resp.
=> `const { status } = await Camera.requestMicrophonePermissionsAsync()`;

```
if (status == 'granted') navigation.navigate(' .....
```

Also tried it within useEffect of the comp - no difference

App.json (extract)
...

```
"android": {
"googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
"adaptiveIcon": {
"foregroundImage": "./src/assets/",
"backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
},
"package": ,
"versionCode": 12,
"softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan",
"permissions": ["CAMERA", "RECORD_AUDIO", "NOTIFICATION", "WRITE_SETTINGS", "VIBRATE", "READ_PHONE_STATE",
"READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION", "ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"],
"useNextNotificationsApi": true
},
```

...

Environment

```
EAS CLI 3.7.2 environment info:
System:
  OS: Windows 10 10.0.19045
Binaries:
  Node: 16.13.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
  Yarn: 1.22.5 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
  npm: 9.1.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
Utilities:
  Git: 2.39.0.
npmPackages:
  expo: 48.0.0 => 48.0.0
  expo-dev-client: ~2.1.4 => 2.1.4
  expo-updates: ~0.16.3 => 0.16.3
  react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
  react-dom: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
  react-native: 0.71.3 => 0.71.3
  react-native-web: ~0.18.7 => 0.18.12
Project workflow: managed

EXPO CLI 48.0.0 environment info:
System:
  OS: Windows 10 10.0.19045
Binaries:
  Node: 16.13.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
  Yarn: 1.22.5 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
  npm: 9.1.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  Watchman: 20200730.120504.0 - 
IDEs:
  Android Studio: AI-221.6008.13.2211.9514443
npmPackages:
  @expo/metro-config: ^0.5.2 => 0.5.2
  expo: 48.0.0 => 48.0.0
  react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
  react-dom: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
  react-native: 0.71.3 => 0.71.3
  react-native-web: ~0.18.7 => 0.18.12
Expo Workflow: managed
```

Sentry Error Output:

> ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap

> com.facebook.react.viewmanagers.RNSVGPathManagerDelegate in setProperty in Zeile 72
> com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater in updateProps in Zeile 46
> com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager in updateProperties in Zeile 84
> com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager in updateProperties in Zeile 142
> com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$UpdatePropertiesOperation in execute in Zeile 93
> com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$1 in run in Zeile 915
> com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue in flushPendingBatches in Zeile 1026
> com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue in access$2600 in Zeile 47
> com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback in doFrameGuarded in Zeile 1086
> com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedFrameCallback in doFrame in Zeile 29
> com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher in doFrame in Zeile 175
> com.facebook.react.modules.core.ChoreographerCompat$FrameCallback$1 in doFrame in Zeile 85
> android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord in run in Zeile 1032
> android.view.Choreographer in doCallbacks in Zeile 845
> android.view.Choreographer in doFrame in Zeile 777
> android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver in run in Zeile 1020
> android.os.Handler in handleCallback in Zeile 873
> android.os.Handler in dispatchMessage in Zeile 99
> android.os.Looper in loop in Zeile 205
> android.app.ActivityThread in main in Zeile 6991
> java.lang.reflect.Method in invoke
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller in run in Zeile 493
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit in main in Zeile 884

Comment: Update:
still happens - even with expo sdk 48
installation of expo-barcodescanner & face detector with no effect